# OpenVPN client fails to re-connect after internet connection re-established

Tags: debian, openvpn, shorewall

I'm running miniPC with Debian and shorewall on it + and OpenVPN client. All is running smoothly unless my isp modem loses connection. After the connection to the internet is re-established, the OpenVPN is not able to connect, unless I HW restart or run

```
systemctl restart openvpn
```

This are the messages I'm getting when I pull network cable from the minipc and put it back

```
kernel: [15984.234741] igb 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: igb: enp1s0 NIC Link is Down
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: carrier lost
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: deleting address fe80::91f0:1a8a:5b0:b967
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: deleting route to 192.168.0.0/24
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: deleting default route via 192.168.0.1
kernel: [15990.843593] igb 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: igb: enp1s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: carrier acquired
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: IAID 31:0b:c8:5e
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: adding address fe80::91f0:1a8a:5b0:b967
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: soliciting an IPv6 router
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: rebinding lease of 192.168.0.49
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: NAK: from 192.168.0.72
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: soliciting a DHCP lease
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: offered 192.168.0.49 from 192.168.0.1
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: probing address 192.168.0.49/24
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: leased 192.168.0.49 for 864000 seconds
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
dhcpcd[489]: enp1s0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
```

and then only getting this messages from openvpn

```
ovpn-client[15057]: Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
ovpn-client[15057]: UDP link local: (not bound)
ovpn-client[15057]: UDP link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1194
ovpn-client[15057]: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
ovpn-client[15057]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
ovpn-client[15057]: SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
ovpn-client[15057]: Restart pause, 5 second(s)
ovpn-client[15057]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
ovpn-client[15057]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1194
```

and my .conf

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Is there a way I could properly restart the OpenVPN service every time it's want to reconnect? I wasn't able to find anything meaningful, all issues are related to issues with making any connection at all.

Comment: What I can see, the OpenVPN updates resolv.conf when connection is made, but the changed dns server are not removed, when the connection is lost. Maybe that is the reason the connection to the server cannot be re-established? Although OpenVPN connects via IP, not dns name.
I guess I could try doing dhcpcd hook to restart open vpn when there is some event on there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, only way to solve this for me was removing persist-tun.

Edit: I unfortunately couldn't find any time to dive deep into why this problem occurs but for my use case which is:

*Using self-hosted OpenVPN for centralized ssh server (to connect via ssh and moderate), for our on-premise servers which have very unstable connection.*

Removing persist-tun had no impact for this use case and solved the client reconnection failure.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/562213)

Comment: @deagh this actually *may* solve the described problem. It all depends on other configuration options, in particular those which control dropping of privileges. I agree that a little explanation of *why* the problem appeared and *how* this solution helped will not hurt.